# What all is covered under the term employment particulars?

Tags: career-development, india, continuing-education

Don't know if this question belongs on this site, but I'll still post anyway...

I am currently employed and looking for higher education opportunities. One of the universities where I am applying has mentioned "All employment particulars since the date of graduation" as a necessary requirement to apply. However, the option allows only one JPG (or JPEG) image to be uploaded (believe me, I've tried uploading multiple). What exactly might be expected there? My guess is my offer of employment or letter of appointment, neither of which am I allowed to share (contractual obligation).

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to ask **them** instead of the internet? How could any of us possibly know what **they** mean?

Comment: @joeqwerty, of course, that was my first thought, but since its the weekend here no one answered the calls or replied to the emails and the deadline is like 12 hours away, I just gambled on asking here.

Comment: Sounds like resume info to me but no way to know what all they want without asking.

Comment: The fact they want a jpg file means that they weren't planing on pulling the text from a CV/Resume. I have no idea what they want. I also think that you might be forced to guess

Comment: Out of interest, what have you been trying to upload?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, I simply gave them a copy of my client's offer letter (don't confuse this with the company's offer letter, I work at a service based company) and they haven't yet barked, so I am guessing it has worked.

Answer (score 3):

As of in the UK, it means an official document written by your former employers stating the main conditions of employment when you started to work for them.

For details, read [the official uk government page](https://www.gov.uk/employment-contracts-and-conditions/written-statement-of-employment-particulars)

Comment: Um, and as per India?

Comment: @justanotherguy You didn't specify that India was important to you and unfortunately the Stack Exchange crystal ball feature is not available yet.